# Jdbm2 Tree index usage

Tags: java, key-value-store

I have built a Btree index using jdbm2 on the disk and now looking forward to use the index. Specifically, I need to query the index and get tuples based upon the selection predicate. 
I understand I must be creating a record manager with the file name persisted on the disk, some thing like mentioned below, However, I am lost with documentation as to how to utilize the BTree from the record manager object and how should I be passing the condition to search on the BTree index. It would be of great help if someone explains me. Thank you.
`RecordManager recMan = RecordManagerFactory.createRecordManager(fileName);`

Answer (score 0):

`recordManager.treeMap("testIndex")` either creates a new index for you or loads an existing one with this name. Index name can be a combination of table & column name if there are multiple indices being built.

The way you would go about doing it is by first identifying the column name being used & then pulling out the data for indices from recordmanager with that name. You would get a list of objects for that index.